# TarsosDSP Clap Detection

Tags: java, android, tarsosdsp

I decided to try out developing for android studio and designed an app that listens for a clap then performs an action of some sort. My problem lies in using TarsosDSP.

I want to run the `Listener` class as an `IntentService`, so I can lock my phone and it still listens. However I'm having trouble setting up the `AudioDispatcher` and `TarsosDSPAudioInputStream`.

Here's the `onHandleIntent` so far:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent Intent) {
        AudioDispatcher mDispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(TarsosDSPAudioInputStream, SAMPLE_RATE, BUFFER_OVERLAP);
        double threshold = 8;
        double sensitivity = 20;

        PercussionOnsetDetector mPercussionDetector = new PercussionOnsetDetector(22050, 1024,
                new OnsetHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleOnset(double time, double salience) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Clap detected!");
                    }
                }, sensitivity, threshold);

        mDispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mPercussionDetector);
        new Thread(mDispatcher).start();
    }
```

I guess more specifically, I'm not sure how I should define the `TarsosDSPAudioInputStream` object. [The documentation](https://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-2.3/TarsosDSP-2.3-Documentation/be/tarsos/dsp/io/TarsosDSPAudioInputStream.html) says it's an interface, but I don't know how that works. I'm super new to Android Studio and java but have a year of experience with C++ as it's part of my major.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TarsosDSP already has an implementation for android. They have an [AudioDispatcherFactory](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/android/be/tarsos/dsp/io/android/AudioDispatcherFactory.java) class and fromDefaultMicrophone(...) method.

So you can use this method to initialize audio dispatcher instance and add any available processors to it. In your case PercussionOnsetDetector

```
    AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);

    double threshold = 8;
    double sensitivity = 20;

    PercussionOnsetDetector mPercussionDetector = new PercussionOnsetDetector(22050, 1024,
            new OnsetHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handleOnset(double time, double salience) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Clap detected!");
                }
            }, sensitivity, threshold);

    mDispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mPercussionDetector);
    new Thread(mDispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher").start();
```

Comment: Okay I understand now. So you override what happens when the percussion detector detects the clap. Then this implementation is put into the `mDispatcher` and `Thread` is started in the very last line. This makes sense, thank you. It's always a pain trying to understand new libraries.

Comment: No pain no gain :) and fortunately tarsosdsp is a well documented lib. thanks to the authors.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the right one, however it does not detect clap with

```
threshold = 8
```

for me.
The following code detects the clap well:

```
 final AudioDispatcher fromDefaultMicrophone = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050, 1024, 0);
        double threshold = 6; // lower it a bit
        double sensitivity = 20;

        PercussionOnsetDetector mPercussionDetector = new PercussionOnsetDetector(22050, 1024,
                new OnsetHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleOnset(double time, double salience) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Clap detected!");
                        startAlarm();
                    }
                }, sensitivity, threshold);

        fromDefaultMicrophone.addAudioProcessor(mPercussionDetector);
        new Thread(fromDefaultMicrophone,"Audio Dispatcher").start();
```